# How can i edit documents in shopware 6.5 with an app

Tags: shopware, shopware6

How can i edit documents like invoices in an app in shopware 6.5?
In Shopware 6.4 I created a file in  custom/apps/MyApp/Resources/views/documents/base.html.twig. In Shopware 6.5.1 I created the same file but nothing happens even after clearing the cache

```
{% sw_extends '@Framework/documents/base.html.twig' %}
{% block document_body %}My new Content
{% endblock %}
```